# Access Denied while executiing jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one function in jquery to process on iframe but it is giving error : Access denied.
I am using IE 8
PFB the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
</script> 


</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com"   id="idIframe" onload="resizeIframe(this)"  ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried debugging also but i cant find the exact solution...
Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allowed to access the DOM of other sites that you've loaded into a frame.

Presumably `www.mysite.com` is not the site that the iframe itself appears on. (Note that `mysite.com` and `www.mysite.com` are different sites).

Comment: then how to get the width and height of the inner site in iframe?

Comment: You can't. If you could then you would be able to invade your visitor's privacy in some fairly interesting ways (such as testing the length of a page in a frame to determine if they were logged into another site (and thus had an account there) or not).